# Get information from another table using intermediate table

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

Here I have three tables `authors`, `books_has_authors` and `books`.

`Books_has_author` is an intermediate table which contains only the primary keys form other two tables. I am trying to write an sql query which will return me **all the books name written by a particular author**. I am new to relational database concepts as well as writing queries for relational databases. I know some `join` queries but I'm really confused how to use them for fetching information through an intermediate table. Any help will be appreciated ! :)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only need to add an additional JOIN, like this:

```
SELECT b.book_id, b.book_name, a.author_id, a.author_name
FROM books b
JOIN books_has_author ba ON ba.books_book_id = b.book_id
JOIN author a ON ba.author_author_id = a.author_id
WHERE a.author_id = xxx
```

Comment: what is b and a as in "b.books_id"  and  "author a"

Comment: It's only an alias for the name of the table. You don't really need it, but that way you write a little less ;)

Comment: thanks :)..can u tell me why i need the additional join..i am totally new to this :(

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
  SELECT b.* FROM books b 
    INNER JOIN books_has_author bha 
    ON bha.books_book_id = b.book_id
    WHERE bha.author_author_id = "$$YOUR AUTHOR ID"
```

Comment: what is b.* and "books b".If you explain a little it will be easier for me :)

Comment: b is the object of books table. * has only one meaning in mysql. you can check the joins in mysql for further reference

Answer (score 1):

use `JOIN` like that :-

```
SELECT *
FROM books
JOIN books_has_author ON books_has_author.books_book_id = books.book_id
JOIN author ON books_has_author.author_author_id = author.author_id
WHERE author.author_id = '123'
```